# SignalR package for Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, signalr

I was wondering if you could help me. I just saw this video from Microsoft Build 2017 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TrttIkbs6c
Where the developers are creating a web chat using SignalR in a .Net Core 2.0 application.

As I want to make the same type of application using .Net, I was wondering if you know why I can't find the package at 11:57.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-preview2-24996" />
```

[Microsoft Build 2017 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNpaK.png)
To be honest, I can't find a good tutorial with a less recent technology so if you have any suggestion, don't hesitate to tell me ;)

Thanks you !

Comment: You can track this issue as it may be helpful for you: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/429

Answer (score 0):

SignalR for .Net Core is not still released. However if you want, you go and get the code from GitHub and try it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR Core has not been released yet so there are no packages on NuGet. You can however use packages created by the CI build. They are being pushed to MyGet so you would have to add the following feed to your NuGet feeds:

```
https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json
```

Note that SignalR requires a 2.0 runtime which has not shipped yet. One way of getting the right runtime is to clone http://github.com/aspnet/SignalR and run build.cmd/build.sh. The runtime will be installed in the .dotnet folder in your profile and you will need to run dotnet.exe from this location.